# "Mark all as read" in Messages... doesn't mark all as read?

Tags: sms

I've asked the Microsoft Launcher to add a badge (unread message count) to the Messages app's icon

The badge always shows "34" even after I've done "Mark all as read" in the app.

Any clue as to how getting the count to 0 so that the badge disappears when I have no unread text messages?

Comment: What phone do you use (Phone model and Android version)? App icon badges with numbers are supported since Android 8. Some device are able to show them before 8 but these devices require a non-standardized way.

Comment: Oops... I must confess I didn't provide much information about my setup... My Nokia 7.1 phone runs Android One 9 with the Microsoft Launcher.